# Passing query parameters to connection string in flyway

Tags: java, mysql, flyway

i'm using flyway migrate `./gradlew flywayMigrate` to run the flyway scripts.

How can we pass query params like socketTimeout to the url like, `jdbc:mariadb:aurora://myHost/db?socketTimeout=0` using the [Flyway Config](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/parameters/url).

As queries longer than 10 secs are timing out in MySQL, i need to pass the query param socketTimeout param .

I tried passing it like their [example](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/usage/gradle/migrate)
`url = 'jdbc:hsqldb:file:/db/flyway_sample;shutdown=true'` but it doesn't work.

These are configured in the `gradle.properties`

```
    flyway.url=jdbc:mariadb:aurora://localhost:3306/schema
    flyway.user=username
    flyway.password=pass
```

Comment: What was the exact URL you tried?

Comment: I used jdbc:mariadb:aurora://localhost:3306/schema for the flyway url. when i add socketTimeout=0 to the string it is creating a new schema with name "schema?socketTimeout=0"

Comment: Sorry to be labouring the question, but - the exact URL that failed, you mean it was jdbc:mariadb:aurora://localhost:3306/schema?socketTimeout=0 ? Because that is correct according to the documentation.

Comment: I've tried on my own instance, and adding `?socketTimeout=0` to a working URL appears fine to me.

Comment: Did you use ./gradlew flywayMigrate --debug and use the gradle.properties for flyway.url and other properties? Was a new schema created or used existing one.